# Extrinsic vs intrinsic geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesics

Let’s say I have two geodesics on an embedded surface. If I was to find the separation vector of two geodesics, find the double derivative of that vector and then project it onto the surface, would I expect to get the same result as if I had done this analysis intrinsically?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not. The *shape tensor* of the submanifold (also called the *second fundamental form*, or *extrinsic curvature tensor*) gets in the way. If you only took one derivative, then the answer is yes, since the tangential projection of the ambient connection equals the Levi-Civita connection of the submanifold. However, you’re talking about second derivatives, so curvature plays a role. If all you want to know is that your statement is false (rather than knowing what the correct statement is), then it is actually relatively easy to justify.

To fix the notation, let $(\widetilde{M},\tilde{g})$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold and $M\subset \widetilde{M}$ a semi-Riemannian submanifold. We shall denote the covariant derivatives in the ambient space $\widetilde{M}$ by $D$ and that in $M$ by $\nabla$. Suppose for contradiction it was true that for all vector fields $X,Y,\psi$ tangent to $M$, we have that
\begin{align}
(D_XD_Y\psi)_{\parallel}&=\nabla_X\nabla_Y\psi,
\end{align}
i.e the tangential projection of the second ambient covariant derivative equals the second covariant derivative on the submanifold. Then, keeping in mind that $[X,Y]$ is again tangent to $M$ (since $X,Y$ are), we have that the parallel projection of the ambient curvature tensor, $\tilde{R}$ would equal the curvature tensor $R$ of the submanifold, because
\begin{align}
\bigg(\widetilde{R}(X,Y)\psi\bigg)_{\parallel}&=\bigg(D_XD_Y\psi-D_YD_X\psi-[X,Y]\bigg)_{\parallel}\\
&=\nabla_X\nabla_Y\psi-\nabla_Y\nabla_X\psi-[X,Y]\\
&=R(X,Y)\psi.
\end{align}
This implies that if your ambient manifold $\widetilde{M}$ has vanishing curvature tensor, i.e is flat, then so is your submanifold. This is obviously absurd, for example $\Bbb{R}^n$ is flat for obvious reasons but the sphere $S^{n-1}$ (with its usual induced metric) has non-trivial intrinsic curvature.

---

**The Correct Statement.**

If you want the correct statement, then let $\alpha:TM\oplus TM\to (TM)^{\perp}$ the shape tensor, and let $\alpha^*:TM\oplus (TM)^{\perp}\to TM$ be its adjoint relative to the metric. Then, generally speaking for any vector field $\Psi$ defined on $M$ but not necessarily tangent to $M$, we have for any vector field $Y$ tangent to $M$,
\begin{align}
D_Y\Psi&=\nabla_Y(\Psi_{\parallel})+\nabla_Y^{\perp}(\Psi_{\perp})+\alpha(Y,\Psi_{\parallel})-\alpha^*(Y,\Psi_{\perp}).
\end{align}
Here, $\nabla,\nabla^{\perp}$ are the connections induced by parallel and normal projections of $D$. Hence, if we specialize to $\psi$ which is tangential to $M$, then
\begin{align}
D_XD_Y\psi&=D_X(\nabla_Y\psi+\alpha(Y,\psi))\\
&=\nabla_X(\nabla_Y\psi)+\nabla_X^{\perp}\left(\alpha(Y,\psi)\right)+\alpha(X,\nabla_Y\psi)-\alpha^*(X,\alpha(Y,\psi)).
\end{align}
In particular, the tangential component is
\begin{align}
\bigg(D_XD_Y\psi\bigg)_{\parallel}&=\nabla_X\nabla_Y\psi-\alpha^*(X,\alpha(Y,\psi)).
\end{align}
So, indeed, as I mentioned in the beginning, you see that the shape tensor gets in the way.

Btw we can go one step further and compute curvatures: interchanging $X,Y$, subtracting the two equations, and subtracting a Lie bracket term $[X,Y]$, we see that
\begin{align}
\bigg(\widetilde{R}(X,Y)\psi\bigg)_{\parallel}&=R(X,Y)\psi +\alpha^*(Y,\alpha(X,\psi))-\alpha^*(X,\alpha(Y,\psi)).
\end{align}
This is the famous [Gauss-equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations) (i.e the first out of the Gauss-Codazzi equations) and it tells you how exactly the parallel projection of your ambient curvature tensor is related to the intrinsic curvature tensor of your submanifold, and its shape-tensor (i.e the extrinsic curvature). Note that in the case $\widetilde{M}=\Bbb{R}^n$ and $M=S^{n-1}$ which I mentioned above, the LHS would vanish, but the term $R(X,Y)\psi$ does not vanish in general (because the sphere is intrinsically curved), but this is compensated for accordingly by the shape tensor (its extrinsic curvature) such that the RHS also vanishes.

---

**Technical Remark.**

You’re asking about geodesics, i.e covariant derivatives along curves, so strictly speaking the above formulae need to be modified (the proper way would be to consider pullback bundles but whatever…)